# linux C++ gmake "No rule to make target"

Tags: c++, linux, gnu-make, makefile

It's been a couple decades since I've had to manage makefiles.  I've checked existing answers here, as well as googling elsewhere.  When I use the target:  `$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)`
I'm stumped as to why my makefile is failing with:

`$ make
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/SRecord.o', needed by 'bin/main'.  Stop.`

Here's the Makefile:

```
# execute `make D='-g'` to make with debug symbols
DEFS := $(D)
CC := gcc $(DEFS)
CFLAGS := -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
CXX := g++ $(DEFS)
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra

BIN := bin
SRC := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB := lib

#LIBSOURCES := $(wildcard $(LIB)/*.cpp)
#LIBOBJECTS := $(LIBSOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
#OBJECTS := $(subst $(LIB)/,,$(LIBOBJECTS))

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

# SOURCES := \
#   $(SRC)/main.cpp \
#   $(SRC)/SerialPort.cpp \
#   $(SRC)/ShadowUpdate.cpp \
#   $(SRC)/SRecord.cpp

# OBJECTS := \
#   $(SRC)/SerialPort.o \
#   $(SRC)/ShadowUpdate.o \
#   $(SRC)/SRecord.o

EXECUTABLE := main

#
# Targets
#
.PHONY: clean all
all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    $(RM) $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS)

run: all
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

# $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*
$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE) -L$(LIB) $^ -o $@ 

#
# Dependencies - must be at end of makefile
#
DEPDIR := .d
$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) >/dev/null)
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

POSTCOMPILE = @mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@

%.o: %.c
%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(CC) -c -o $*.o $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

%.o: %.cpp
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(CXX) -c -o $*.o $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SOURCES))))
```

It works with the commented out target: `# $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(SRC)/*`

But, I want to be able to have a more complex project than simply listing all the source files as dependencies to the executable.

Here's my file tree:

```
src/
src/SerialPort.cpp
src/SRecord.cpp
src/ShadowUpdate.cpp
src/main.cpp
include
include/ShadowUpdate.h
include/SerialPort.h
include/SRecord.h
include/the_exo.h
bin/
bin/main
Makefile
lib/
.d/
```

The automatic dependency generation isn't working either, even though it is straight from GNU's website.

Comment: Your dependency handling can be fixed, and that will fix your rule-finding problem along the way. Right now you're putting object files (`SRecord.o`) in `src/`; do you want them there, or `bin/`, or `obj/`, or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Beta.  I'm fine with the objects in src for now.  I'm thinking I was confused about how much gmake did for you and how much had to be explicitly stated.  I've posted my revised Makefile below - it works.

If the project grows much, I'll be rearranging stuff for sure.  Now that  understand the game, I'll be able to handle the extra complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about what the `%` expands to in

```
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d
```

plugging in `src/SRecord.o`:

```
src/SRecord.o: src/SRecord.cpp .d/src/SRecord.d
```

Can you see the issue? Try the following instead

```
$(SRC)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(SRC)/$(DEPDIR)/%.d
```

You won't need the lines that override the built-in recipes (`%.o: %.cpp`), get rid of them.

Comment: Your solution for the object files is correct.  However, the "override" targets are absolutely necessary in order to build the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity to anyone looking for the answer in the future, I'm posting my revised Makefile:

```
BIN := bin
SRC := src
INCLUDE := include
LIB := lib

# execute `make D='-g'` to make with debug symbols
DEFS := $(D)
CC := gcc $(DEFS)
CFLAGS := -I$(INCLUDE) -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra
CXX := g++ $(DEFS)
CXXFLAGS := -I$(INCLUDE) -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra

#LIBSOURCES := $(wildcard $(LIB)/*.cpp)
#LIBOBJECTS := $(LIBSOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)
#OBJECTS := $(subst $(LIB)/,,$(LIBOBJECTS))

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.cpp)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.cpp=%.o)

EXECUTABLE := main

#
# Targets
#
.PHONY: clean all
all: $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    $(RM) $(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS)

run: all
    ./$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE)

$(BIN)/$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -L$(LIB) $^ -o $@ 

#
# Dependencies - must be at end of makefile
#
DEPDIR := $(SRC)/.d
$(shell mkdir -p $(DEPDIR) >/dev/null)
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td

POSTCOMPILE = @mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d && touch $@

%.o: %.c
%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

%.o: %.cpp
$(SRC)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $(DEPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEPDIR)/%.d

include $(wildcard $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SOURCES))))
```

To clarify my comment to the above answer, if I comment out the "override" target (`%.o: %.cpp`), here's the output:

```
$ make clean; make
rm -f bin/main
rm -f src/SRecord.o src/SerialPort.o src/ShadowUpdate.o src/main.o
g++  -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra   -c -o src/SRecord.o src/SRecord.cpp
g++  -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra   -c -o src/SerialPort.o src/SerialPort.cpp
g++  -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra   -c -o src/ShadowUpdate.o src/ShadowUpdate.cpp
g++  -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra   -c -o src/main.o src/main.cpp
g++  -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Llib src/SRecord.o src/SerialPort.o src/ShadowUpdate.o src/main.o -o bin/main
```

Clearly, the dependencies are not being made.  My rule was not executed.

But, with the empty `%.o: %.cpp` target in place, the make performs as expected:

```
$ make clean; make
rm -f bin/main
rm -f src/SRecord.o src/SerialPort.o src/ShadowUpdate.o src/main.o
g++  -c -o src/SRecord.o -MT src/SRecord.o -MMD -MP -MF src/.d/SRecord.Td -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra src/SRecord.cpp
g++  -c -o src/SerialPort.o -MT src/SerialPort.o -MMD -MP -MF src/.d/SerialPort.Td -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra src/SerialPort.cpp
g++  -c -o src/ShadowUpdate.o -MT src/ShadowUpdate.o -MMD -MP -MF src/.d/ShadowUpdate.Td -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra src/ShadowUpdate.cpp
g++  -c -o src/main.o -MT src/main.o -MMD -MP -MF src/.d/main.Td -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra src/main.cpp
g++  -Iinclude -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -Llib src/SRecord.o src/SerialPort.o src/ShadowUpdate.o src/main.o -o bin/main
```